# composite design in Map.putAll(Map) method

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a doubt. `Map.putAll(Map`) method is implemented using composite pattern, I want to know , is it correct ?

Because `PutAll()` method is present in all the decedents of Map irrespective of leaf or non leaf.

My doubt is, in composite class `add(Composite)` will be present in non leaf classes, but in Map it is present at the interface level, that means even the leaf class have a aggregation link to the component , this contradicts the class diagram of composite design pattern as it shows the aggregation link from composite to component , not from leaf to component. Kindly help

Thanks
Praveen B

Comment: What do you consider _leaf_ and _non-leaf_ classes? Which `Map` implementation are you talking about?

Comment: provide some links to your claims/terminology - we are not psychic...

Comment: Java Map Implementaion. Leaf is the one which do not have further children. I am not sure if Map.putAll(Map) is designed based on composite pattern. i have seen some sites quote it as example for composite design pattern

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698086/multiple-leaf-methods-problem-in-composite-pattern?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern):

> The composite pattern describes that a group of objects is to be treated in the same way as a single instance of an object. The intent of a composite is to "compose" objects into tree structures to represent part-whole hierarchies. Implementing the composite pattern lets clients treat individual objects and compositions uniformly.

By reading this, you should answer your question:  ***A Map is not a composite***

When you write:

> map1.putAll(map2)

You are not creating a parent-child relationship between map1 and map2. You just put all the map2 content in map1.

Comment: does that mean there is no composite pattern in map1.PutAll(map2) method?

Comment: No there is not. A composite pattern is a structural pattern. It is not at the method level but at the class level.